# Can we add Then statement while generating karate test using karate-core?

Tags: karate

I am creating karate feature file from postman collection using karate-core in java. I have observed that there are no assertions added there. Is there any way from where we can add **Then** statement from postman collection it self.

Code generated by karate-core

```
# Find student by ID
        Given url '{{baseUrl}}/student/:studentId'
        And header Accept = 'application/json'
        When method GET

# Deletes a student
        Given url '{{baseUrl}}/student/:studentId'
        And header Accept = 'application/json'
        When method DELETE
```

Comment: conversion of Postman collections including assertions is a paid-upgrade in the Karate IDE plugins for VS Code and Intellij. you can find a demo here: (1:06) https://youtu.be/dhIigSSt_wg?t=66